# Computed props not working Vue JS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

im learning vue js following a channel on YT, the video was sent last year, so i think its not working due to some changes on VueJS itself, but it would be great if you guys could help me with this

codeio link: http://codepen.io/myrgato/pen/BWWxdQ

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
  <p>Counter: {{counter}}</p>
  <p>Clicks: {{clicks}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    clicks: 0
  },
  methods: {
    increment(){
      this.clicks++;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    counter(){
      return this.clicks * 2; 
    }
  }
});
```

its supposed to calculate the amount of clicks, then use a computed proprerty to display a counter that equals clicks times two, but for some reason it isnt working..

Comment: Although it might not be the cause, try removing `counter` from `data`

Comment: Wait, it worked, why tho?

Comment: Hmm, did it changed since last year? Cause check this video out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx2WnT_sckA&list=PL55RiY5tL51p-YU-Uw90qQH419BM4Iz07&index=4 , it works there

Comment: Which version of vue are you using?

Comment: Im using version 2.2.2

Comment: You should not have both a data item and a computed of the same name. Which do you think `this.counter` would refer to? How would you refer to the other one?

Comment: This tutorial is apparently getting around lol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707977/vue-2-0-computed-issue/42708216#42708216

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue 2.0 - Computed issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707977/vue-2-0-computed-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Short but the full answer:

Never use the same name for `data` variable and `computed`.

Think about data & computed as the same object, so names can't be duplicated.

Comment: They can be duplicated but not without repurcussions, vue 2.1.0 that I use throws an error that the `computed` property will overwrite the `data` property.

Comment: They SHOULD NOT BE. It is against one of the most important practices which is CREATE MAINTAINABLE CODE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. The trick is to:

- use a different name for the computed property (here `counter2`)
- and to use a lambda function with a single parameter (here `x`) instead of `this`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    clicks: 0
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.clicks++;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    counter2: x => x.clicks * 2
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
  <p>Counter: {{counter2}}</p>
  <p>Clicks: {{clicks}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't sure of why this happened I ran two tests on jsFiddle:

[sample A:](http://jsfiddle.net/k0u50mL3/2/)

[sample B](http://jsfiddle.net/k0u50mL3/3/)

Here you would notice that in sample B the order of execution is:

1. Data properties get added first.
2. The created hook is invoked.
3. The computed property calculates the value of counter

In sample A, the step 3 never happens.

In vue2.1.0, you would get a warning like :

[Vue warn](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/2040): existing instance property "haveTrigger" will be overwritten by a computed property with the same name.

---

Further checking in the docs I found that this warning is suppressed in vue 2.2.2 hence you never received it, but along with it I found this interesting piece:

> Props and computed properties are now defined on a component's prototype instead of as self properties on each instance. This avoids many calls to Object.defineProperty and improves component initialization performance. This will only affect you if you rely on hasOwnProperty checks on props and computed properties, which should be extremely rare, but we are documenting it here to be explicit about the change.
>
> [Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases)

```js
var fancyConstructor = function () {
  this.value = 5
}

var instance = new fancyConstructor()

fancyConstructor.prototype.value = 5000
fancyConstructor.prototype.someOtherValue = 5000

console.log(instance.value)
console.log(instance.someOtherValue)
```

you can also go deep down in each component to find that there are indeed computed properties set to `counter`.

[image]

The above snippet will illustrate what happens if a property by the same name is there on the object as well as the prototype.